# Javascript get the string between two symbols

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following string and I'm trying to retrieve the string between two symbols

```
http://mytestdomain.com/temp-param-page-2/?wpv_paged_preload_reach=1&wpv_view_count=1&wpv_post_id=720960&wpv_post_search&wpv-women-clothing[]=coats
```

I need to retrieve `wpv-women-clothing[]` or any other string between the last `&` and the last `=` in the URL

Should I use regex for this or is there a function in Javascript/jQuery already well suited for this?

Thanks

Comment: I tend to use [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) for this. But regex masters will help you.

Comment: I'm really new to complex string manipulations, can you offer some tips on how I might achieve this?

Comment: you dont need regex, this is a url, it is assumed that there will be no characters in between that match to '&' ot '='. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Comment: Try this:

    var str= 'http://mytestdomain.com/temp-param-page-2/?wpv_paged_preload_reach=1&wpv_view_count=1&wpv_post_id=720960&wpv_post_search&wpv-women-clothing[]=coats';
    
    var regex = new RegExp(/&\w*=/g);
    
    str.match(regex);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "http://mytestdomain.com/temp-param-page-2/?wpv_paged_preload_reach=1&wpv_view_count=1&wpv_post_id=720960&wpv_post_search&wpv-women-clothing[]=coats";
var last =str.split('&').pop().split('=')
console.log(last[0]) // wpv-women-clothing[]
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/oj1eL1wa/)**

Split the string on the ampersands (`.split('&')`), take the last one (`.pop()`), then split again on the = (`.split('=')`) and use the first result `last[0]`.

Comment: Not gonna add an other answer since it's similar, but alternatively, you could do that : `str.split(/[&=]/).splice(-2,1);`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Awesome. Did not know you can use a `regular expression` for the selector. Learned something. This comment is the best from both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Group index 1 contains your desired output,

```
\&([^=]*)(?==[^&=]*$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iM7vX1/22)

```
> var re = /\&([^=]*)(?==[^&=]*$)/g;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
... console.log(m[1]);
... }
wpv_post_search&wpv-women-clothing[]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.*&(.*?)=.*
```

This should do it.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5bT3/1

Answer (score -1):

Can you try:

```
var String = "some text";
String = $("<div />").html(String).text();

$("#TheDiv").append(String);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to format your answer. Please also take a look into [answer]